# with div(width:auto) in a div(width:auto)

Tags: css, html

Hi guys I've got a problem with some `div` with `width:auto`.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="greenMenu">
    <div class="btn">
        <img src="img/image.png" width="57" height="46" />
        <div class="area">
            <div class="txt">A Lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn">
        <img src="img/image.png" width="57" height="46" />
        <div class="area">
            <div class="txt">A Lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.greenMenu {
    position:absolute; 
    top:83px; 
    left:220px; 
    width:auto; 
    height:47px; 
    background:url(../img/prod-uova-ripMenu.png) left top repeat;
}

.greenMenu .btn {
    background:#090; 
    float:left; 
    margin-top:1px; 
    margin-left:6px; 
    *display:inline; 
    _display:inline; 
    width:auto; 
    height:43px; 
    position:relative;
}

.greenMenu .btn img {
    border:none; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    z-index:2;
}

.greenMenu .btn .area {
    background:#53882d; 
    width:auto; 
    height:32px; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:5px; 
    left:0px; 
    z-index:1;
}

.greenMenu .btn .area .txt {
    float:left; 
    margin:7px 13px 0 60px;
}
```

The problem is: the `greenMenu` cannot expand its width and in the same time `div.btn`  width is 0.

Comment: Everything within `.greenMenu .btn ` is `position: absolute;` that's why it wont stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use following code there:

```
 position: absolute;
```